# Any way to embed p::first-letter within text body

Tags: html, css, sass

so i am using the `::first-letter` selector to increase the font-size of the first letter within a blog post (standard-ish ? ). Anyway, when i do this, i am getting this result

[image]

Anyway, as you can probably tell, i want the text to be at the same level as the rest of the body, similar to this

[image]

Is there any way to achieve this? I have tried adding margins/padding to no result. Had also tried `initial-letter` prior to this. I could probably hack a solution but i don't think it would be best practice.

**CSS**

```
.blog-text {
  line-height: 26px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.blog-text:first-child p::first-letter{
  font-size: 300%;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: did you try `float:left` ?

Comment: Not till now. Make an answer and i'll accept, thankyou!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `float-left` for that first letter pseudo-element. Since it will still be a little bit higher than the following letters, you can fine-tune the actual position with a `margin-top`setting as shown below. I would also recommend to fine-tune the `font-size` of that first letter in relation to the font-size of the subsequent text size.

```css
.blog-text {
  line-height: 26px;
}

.blog-text:first-child p::first-letter{
  font-size: 56px;
  float:left;
  margin: 6px 3px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="blog-text">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
.blog-text:first-child p::first-letter{
  initial-letter: 2;
}
```

Not available on all browsers though, see https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-initial-letter.

Comment: Looks like it's safari only https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-initial-letter

Comment: Cool, add the alternative solution about using float left too if you don't mind

Answer (score 0):

Why not using a custom span class?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Drop Cap span style</title>
<style>
span.dropcap{
  display:block;
  float:left;
  line-height:1em;
  width:48px;
  padding:0;
  text-align:center;
  margin:0 6px 3px 0;
  font-size:300%
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p>
<span class="dropcap">W</span>orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</p>
</body>
```

This produces fair margins and alignments:

```css
span.dropcap{
  display:block;
  float:left;
  line-height:1em;
  width:48px;
  padding:0;
  text-align:center;
  margin:0 6px 3px 0;
  font-size:300%
}
```

```html
<p><span class="dropcap">W</span>orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
```